# Testing for false with the Twitter Gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the Twitter gem, and I want to take a list of users from my `Friend` model and test to see if they're being following a Twitter user, then ... unfollow if the Twitter API returns `false`. Trouble is, it seems the code I'm using below never evaluates as false, even when the API returns `false` so it's always reverting to the `else` section.

I've tried variations like `if ret == 'false'` and it's not worked.

```
        ret = @t.friendship?(@id_str, f.screen_name)
          if ret == false
            @t.unfollow(f.screen_name)
            puts "#{f.screen_name} has been unfollowed."
            self.update_unfollowed_column(f.id, false)
          else
            self.update_following_column(f.id)
          end
```

In the console, though, if I do:

```
r = t.friendship?('user1', 'user2')
 => false
```

And then, I can do:

```
 r == false
 => true
```

So, I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong with the code in my `Friend` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the if statement, try debugging what the result is from the `friendship?` method:

```
logger.info ret.class.name # => FalseClass if it's actually false, 
                           # => String if it's 'false'

logger.info ret.inspect # => "false" if it's false.

logger.info((ret == false).inspect) # => Should be "true"
```